pip install with keyring-provider is not working
I have keyring installed as the artifactory repo where I download the package required authentication.
Operating System is Windows 10.
I referred this document and decided to use keyring with pip.
Command I use is
pip install <custom package> --keyring-provider import -i 'https://<artifacotry-url>.com/artifactory/api/pypi/<org>-local-pypi-playground/simple'

benefit of doubt, I tried --keyring-provider subprocess as well.
What I get is.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <custom package> (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for <custom package>

I confirmed that it works when I use .netrc and url based authentication. Problem is only when using keyring. I can also see credentials set using keyring in Windows credential manager.
